# Is it safe to use asynchronous loading with RequireJS to define a module, and use it right after in immediate function?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

My example code looks like this:

```
/*global define, require*/
define('api', ['app'], function (app) {
    'use strict';

    return {
        init: function () {
            app.init();
        }
    };
});

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var newrequire,
        requireConfig = {
            baseUrl: 'http://localhost/app/'
        };

    newrequire = require.config(requireConfig);
    newrequire(['api'], function (api) {
        api.init();
    });
})();
```

But I noticed that in some cases (`app` being big JS file, and server or internet connection is slow) it throws me an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined
```

Basically I want to be 100% sure if I can trust, that `api` module is fully loaded and ready to use (not only defined), when I need it inside my immediate function.

Comment: It sounds to me like you answered your own question already. If you get an error sometimes it's a race condition and not safe.

Comment: I also found requirejs hard to use with other libraries and vice-versa. That is why I created a library which is much easier to use and is tested with angular. There is a demo application at the bottom: http://gngeorgiev.github.io/Modulerr.js/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is safe, but there is one thing you need to be aware of - you can't have an existing script with the same name as newly defined module, so in this case:

```
http://localhost/app/api.js
```

If module is not ready requirejs automatically tries to load corresponding to the passed name file, and if the path is correct, it loads the file, instead of defined module.